# Possible two digit hex numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm currently learning about counting theory, and I feel like I am confusing myself with a question asking the following:

Hexadecimal digits are formed from 0-9 and A-F, how many possible digits can be chosen?

This is worded weirdly, but I am assuming it means a combination of digit+character (two character).

I am supposed to either apply the rule of sum or rule of addition when it comes to counting. I Should be using the product rule correct? A0, A1, A2, A3, A4...F6 - (6*10 possibilities)

Comment: There are 16 hex digits: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F. (In hex that is 10 digits). So there are 15*16=240  two digit hex numbers, since the leading digit cannot be 0 (or 16*16=256 if a leading zero is permitted)

Comment: That is *horrible* wording.  You'd be right if it meant what you thought it did.  But it only means that there are 16 digits-- the ten 0-9 and an extra 6 which we choose to use letters to represent..  Your title says two digit numbers but your body says one.  Not sure what the question is.

Comment: This is the complete question, maybe it'll help:  Hexadecimal digits are formed using either a numeric decimal digit or a letter from A to F. How many possible digits can be chosen

Comment: How many possibly digits can be chosen to do what?

Comment: That's it, thats the end of the question

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear, but I think if I understand correctly, you're asking that for each position in a hexadecimal number, how many possibilities can be chosen. In this case, you're using the product rule. If there are 10 possible numbers and six possible letters, in each position, there are 16 possibilities. In this case, if repetition is allowed, the answer is $16^n$ where $n$ is the length of the entire hexadecimal string.

Comment: Probably a leading zero is not allowed, changing the count a bit.